# How to remove line `v u` from a file when line `u v` already exists using unix command

Tags: shell, unix, awk, graph

I have the following test data :

```
a b
a c
b a
b c
b d
c a
c b
c d
d b
d c
```

and I want to remove lines `v u` when line `u v` already exists using unix command. For example here I want to obtain :

```
a b
a c
b c
b d
c d
```

I've tried with an awk script but on a long file it takes too much time :

```
{
if(NR==1){
    n1=$1
    n2=$2
    test=0
    k=0
    i = 0
    column1[i]=$1
    column2[i]=$2
    printf "%s %s\n", column1[i], column2[i]
}
else{
    for(k=0; k<=i;k++){
        if(column1[k]==$2){
            test=1
            tmp=i
            break
        }
    }
    if(test==1){
        if(column2[tmp]==$1){
            n1=$1
            n2=$2
        }
    }
    else if(n1!=$1||n2!=$2){
        n1=$1
        n2=$2
        i++
        column1[i]=$1
        column2[i]=$2
        printf "%s %s\n", column1[i], column2[i]
    }
    test=0
}
}
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be achieved pretty simply:

```
awk '!seen[$1,$2]++ && !seen[$2,$1]' file
```

This only prints lines (the default action) when the first and second column have not yet been seen in either order.

The array `seen` keeps track of every pair of fields by setting a key containing the first and second field. The expression `!seen[key]++` is only true the first time that a specific `key` is tested because the value in the array is incremented each time.